# Using a "spherical frustum" for 3D projection

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am currently writing a transformation from model space to clip space for use in OpenGL. From what i have seen, programmers typically use a traditional rectangular frustum to define the clipping boundaries in their model space. I personally had in mind a shape like a frustum, except the near and far planes are spheres centered at the apex of the frustum (the camera). So something that looks like this:

[image: Circular sector]

The yellow region corresponds to OpenGL's clip space, and the two spheres (depicted as circles in this cross-section image) correspond to OpenGL's `z=-1` (inner sphere) and `z=1` (outer sphere).

Is this a more realistic way to model the projection, or should i stick with the traditional rectangular frustum when designing my projection matrix?

Comment: the traditional frustum is a result of using the projection matrix and bounding `z`, with the circular frustum you need to get the euclidean distance (3 squares and a summation)

Comment: The math isn't my problem. I just wanna know if it would be a realistic projection.

Comment: if you add the vertical lines of the rectangular frustum on your image you'll see it's a small difference anyway for small FoVs

Comment: What about for large ones - for example, 90º  (which is a typical person's FOV)?

Answer (score 1):

No. I'm not sure what you mean to be completely honest, but in either case no.

- Do you mean that the view coordinates (view frustum usually) should be bounded by spheres?

Well in many (all?, most?) large polygons that intersect the clip plane are actually broken in to smaller triangles that don't - otherwise a single big polygon that had one vertex outside would simply be ignored. This is what clipping actually involves.

Remember when you played old games and walked into objects, only to have them disappear if you got too close? Wouldn't it suck if when the corner of a polygon was just outside the view the hole thing vanished? see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) for clarification.

- On the other hand you may have meant the view space should be
  projected onto a sphere instead of a flat plane.

Well a screen is flat, so the objects in a 3d scene are projected onto a flat surface, equivalent to tracing a ray of light from an object towards the camera and finding where it would intersect your monitor. The weird "unrealistic" 3d look is a result of the viewer's eyes being a) not a point camera and b) rarely if ever at the correct distance for the field of view.

Comment: this is the good answer, in short, frustum is a projecton on a plane because Screen is a Plane. projecting into a sphere/cilinder is usefull if screen would be curved (else you will see disturbin distorion.. look at polar distortion to get a Idea creXALBO)

Answer (score 0):

The region defined in this way seems to be more logical than usual frustum for the next reason: in the wide-angle projection (let's say 90-120 degrees) the objects those are close to far plane may disappear and suddenly reappear after just rotating the camera. This happens if the distance (euclidean) from the eye to the object is between the distances from the eye to the center of flat frustum's far plane and it's corner.

Spherical sector should remove this problem. However a new one appears: after projection on the screen surface flat polygons may become warped because of changes in depth calculations. Although I am not sure how exactly that will look like.